# How to purge the checkpoint directory in spark structured streaming

Tags: spark-structured-streaming

I am new to spark structured streaming. I have set up a streaming pipeline from kafka and also set up the checkpoint directory.

Now the offsets are being written to the checkpoint directory and it works fine.

I could see the checkpoint directory keeps increasing. Is there any property in spark to purge this automatically. If not what is a better solution to do this.

I tried to use the property spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.cleanCheckpoints = true. But this does not seem to help.

Comment: The checkpoint directory only keeps the latest 100 batches. Did you see more than that?

Comment: Thanks. Yes the checkpoint directory just keeps the latest 100 batches. In case I am writing the kafka output to a file in writestream for every batch generated. Then can we purge that in the later point. Please suggest. We have a similar scenario to be implemented in coming future.

Comment: Are you using the file sink such as `writeStream.format("parquet").start(...)`?

Comment: Yes. When i try to delete any old file from the saved location. I get error as spark-metadata-0-doesnt-exist-while-compacting-batch-9-structured-streaming-error. Can you please suggest how to overcome this.

Comment: The metadata you mentioned is actually not in the streaming checkpoint. It's inside your output directory to indicate which files are valid to read to implement exactly-once semantics. Yep, the scalability of the file sink has some known issues. I'd suggest you to try https://docs.delta.io/latest/index.html . It has addressed most of issues in the file sink from scratch, for example, it allows you to compact small files concurrently, and you can set the log retention to reduce the metadata size. What you need to do is adding the library and replacing `format("parquet")` with `format("delta")`.